# How can I count active threads in an array and avoid "collection was modified" errors?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I have a collection of Threads in C# (`List<Thread>`) which at certain intervals I want to get the number of them which are actively doing work.

Currently I set the individual threads to null when they are completed. Therefore:

```
private int AliveThreads()
{
    lock (ThreadCollection)
    {
        return ThreadCollection.Count(t => t != null);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to use `lock` to avoid having the error "Collection was modified" but this isn't working. I still get this error from time to time.

Is there something else that might be better?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just remove them from the collection?

Comment: @Galactic They get reused; jobs in a queue are assigned to the threads as they become available (null) so that I can keep, for example, 20 threads busy doing something.

Comment: But you're not actually *reusing* anything, and you're effectively trying to recreate the thread pool.  If you just removed them, then anytime your collection fell below the threshold you see if you can spawn more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just use an interlocked counter; increase this (Interlocked.Increment) **before** starting each thread, and have each thread call Interlocked.Decrement just before they exit. Then you can use Thread.VolatileRead at any point to see how many are active, without any collection.

However, specifically to address the question: if you are using a collection the threads setting the item to null should lock, too:

```
lock(ThreadCollection)
{
    ThreadCollection[index] = null;
}
```

The counter seems far cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
lock (ThreadCollection)
{
    return ThreadCollection.Count(t => t != null);
}
```

is only effective when all other operations on `ThreadCollection` are also surrounded by a `lock()` statement.

> to avoid having the error "Collection was modified"

indicates you are not doing that, the error comes from another piece of code.